# Blend Trees are bad in 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

My project is Isometric 2d with 8 directional movement animations.

As you all know, blend trees are great for blending animation in 3d. It also works in 2d (visual aspect) but "under the hood" I have a lot of issues.
I like to bind Animation Events to different functions. But they trigger more than once, because 2 or 3 animations are being played at the same time in my blend tree (although only the dominant one displayed) if I move in a not straight direction. In other words, if my x and y axis are not equal to 1 or -1.

I found a workaround that checks which animations weight is >= 0.5f, but that doesn't work in all circumstances and i don't know why and I would actually like to know whether there are better ways to workaround this issue.

This issue is present only on the Enemy character, because the x and y axies are not always equal to a whole number, as it modifies x and y based on a direction to the player. The player, on the other hand, works fine with the keyboard, but does not with a joystick due to the same reason.

Could I somehow "clamp" the value to be a whole number of the vector.x and vector.y to be strictly 1 or -1 in this situation? That would help a lot with Animation Events and with that blend tree situation.

For now its just simply doing this:

```
direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", direction.x);
anim.SetFloat("Vertical", direction.y);
```

Then I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", Mathf.Clamp(direction.x, -1, 1));
anim.SetFloat("Vertical", Mathf.Clamp(direction.y, -1, 1));
```

Comment: to those who downvote, at least specify why.
Could not find any info whatsoever in weeks

Comment: I think you don't want clamp between -1 and 1.  I think what you actually want is something like (x > 0) ? 1 : ((x < 0 ) ? -1 : 0)